# time data 'Fri, 03 Dec 2021 11:43:35' does not match format '%a, %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have the following string:`"Fri, 03 Dec 2021 11:43:55"`. I want to convert it to datetime with python.
I am using strptime to convert it to datetime but it doesn't work.
Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime

dte_str = "Fri, 03 Dec 2021 11:43:55"
dte = datetime.strptime(dte_str,"%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

> time data 'Fri, 03 Dec 2021 11:43:35' does not match format '%a, %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
> How to solve the problem please!

Comment: There is a space between `Fri, 03`, so adjust the pattern to `%a, %d..`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM the error message shows that the OP has it correct in the actual code (not the example I assume) - but that doesn't make the error reproducible for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this shows error because it's not actually the same format as your string:

```
dte = datetime.strptime(dte_str,"%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

[image]

There needs to be a space after comma after Friday.
Try this and it works.

```
dte = datetime.strptime(dte_str,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

[image]